# How to upload Mp3 files on Qt (QMediaPlayer)?

Tags: c++, qt, mp3, qmediaplayer

I have to create a Qt application that executes mp3 files. I use the library QMediaPlayer, how can I let the user choose and upload the mp3 file?

Comment: What do you mean by upload exactly ? the user send his mp3 file to your server ?

Comment: no, he has to have the possibility to select a mp3 files from the computer's files(maybe I could use QFileDialog? if yes, how can I use it?)

Comment: so ok if you want to just a media player, you can go to the stackOverflow documentation about Qt. Here: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/qt/7675/multimedia. To use the QFileDialog, just do as the example about the music player I wrote. To have multiple files, use a QMediaPlaylist with the method addMedia() as written in the Video example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QMediaPlayer` has a `setMedia` method which can accept a path to you local .mp3 file. It can be used like this.

```
QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;
player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:\mycoolsong.mp3"));
```

I guess you want to build something like a file explorer from where the user can select from multiple songs. There is a great tutorial for this here: [C++ Qt 49 - QFileSystemModel a simple file explorer example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92biLZST6Vg)